# IIS7 graphic pops up out of nowhere-what reason would that happen & am I compromised?

Tags: iis-7

I had a graphic with IIS7 in the middle of it with "Welcome" in numerous languages around it pop up out of nowhere on my laptop screen. It has happened to me twice now. I am not on a work computer. I feel like people are using my router..idk why, it's a gut feeling..like I'm paying for Internet while they get free use of the Internet. The other day, I saw a network on the list of availables with almost the exact same name as mine except the last number, so I put in my password- it worked. I called the cable company who tells me I have always had 2 connections to the Internet. I outright said, "What are you talking about? Don't you think the guy who installed my service would mention that when showing me how to sign on? Or the many times I called or even on the bill somewhere?" I don't know what is going on!!. Today, my laptop said, "another computer with the same IP is in your network, check your System File log". Am I hacked? Are other people using my router? Can anyone help please??

Comment: You can and should read the documentation for your router, log into it, and change the passcode to something private. You should also research the security options this router supports and implement any of them you can.

Answer (score 1):

The "second connection" is most likely to be that you have a dual-band wireless router - one that broadcasts on both 5Ghz and 2.4Ghz bands. This would explain both the similar network names and the fact that your password worked on both. It could also possibly explain the message referring to another computer with the same IP - if you swapped between the networks it's possible that the router hadn't updated it's list of connected devices for the other one yet and that could potentially make Windows think there was another machine with the same IP. I'd have to know more about the setup before being sure at all on that one.

As for the "IIS7" screen you saw, what you describe sounds exactly like the holding page that IIS7 (Microsoft's Web Server software) displays by default before you configure any sites. That would lead me to think that the screen you saw was a misconfigured web site somewhere - if you weren't trying to visit a website when you saw that it could have been a malware/virus that was trying to display it's site to you but that said site has been taken down or isn't set up properly. In which case I'd recommend running a anti-virus scan such as Windows Defender (included in later version of Windows), or [Trendmirco Housecall](http://housecall.trendmicro.com/uk/index.html#overview) (free scanner, ideal if you're running an older version of Windows such as XP, Vista or 7) and a [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download/) scan to check for any nasties.

It is of course possible that someone is freeloading on your Wifi - it's not uncommon. However there are steps you can take to make this much harder for anyone to do such as making sure the network is set up to use WPA encryption, with a secure password and changing the password periodically to boot off anyone who does get on.

If you can update your question with the make and model of your router I can try point you in the right direction to check/setup these things. Alternatively your cable company will be able to support you (presumably the router was one they supplied?).